# How to login/submit request through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am not sure why selenium is not sending submit request.

edx.py           or Coursera

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://courses.edx.org/login')
email = browser.find_element_by_id('login-email')
email.send_keys('xxxxx@gmail.com')
pwd = browser.find_element_by_id('login-password')
pwd.send_keys('password')
login_attempt = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login"]/button')
login_attempt.submit()
```

Comment: What is the exception details? Please update your question with complete stack trace

Comment: We need more information. Please check [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below CSS Selector

```
action.action-primary.action-update.js-login.login-button
```

Update

Just noticed that you have missing dot (.) in your implementation

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id='login']/button')
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"action.action-primary.action-update.js-login.login-button"}

Comment: Updated Xpath in my answer, please check

Answer (score 0):

try `login_attempt.click()`

[image]

You form not has `action` attribute, so the `form.submit()` won't know the destination to submit.

So for safe purpose, recommend to find the button and click on it. Rather than use the convenient API: `element.submit()`.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code trials to populate the **Email** and **Password** field and `click()` on **Sign in** button you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *elements to be clickable* and you can use the following code block:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://courses.edx.org/login")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input-block#login-email"))).send_keys("Sakim@gmail.com")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.input-block#login-password").send_keys("Sakim")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.action.action-primary.action-update.js-login.login-button").click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: courses_edx_org]